# Shell console clearing

Tags: shell, terminal

Is there a way to clear up what is displayed on the shell console (in ubuntu linux) in just a single key or two? When I get flood of lines from `grep` and that exceeds the height of the window, I want to quickly scroll back to the position where I typed the command after the prompt. I can do so if I had opened a fresh terminal before I type the command, and just go to the initial position. But if keep using the same terminal window, I have to manually find the position. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> is not an answer because it just scrolls, and the contents of the terminal remains. I cannot use `less` because the colored output of grep does not show up in color.

Comment: I'm mildly confused.  Are you looking for something similar to `cls` in DOS?

Comment: I am not familiar with DOS, but if that allows you to clear the window and have your scroll bar at the top position, then that is what I want.

Comment: `cls` in DOS clears the contents of the console and returns you to a blank screen with a fresh command prompt.

Comment: @lszi I see. It's the counterpart to 'reset' that Faheem gave?

Comment: No, `clear` is the counterpart to `cls`.  `reset` does more.  Both will probably work, but based on your description, `reset` is overkill.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The

```
reset
```

command, which is part of [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses#External_links), and is
located in the [ncurses-bin](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ncurses-bin) package on Debian, will completely clear the console. Is that what you want?

Brief summary of `reset` from the man page:

> reset sets cooked and echo modes,
>   turns off cbreak and raw modes, turns
>   on new-line translation and resets any
>   unset special characters to their
>   default values before doing terminal
>   initialization the same way as tset.

As discussed in https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands, and as pointed out by Erik in [Shell console clearing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/shell-console-clearing/10407#10407), `clear` will just clear the screen, `reset` will (as bignose put it), "reset your terminal when it gets messed up by control sequences". Personally, I'm good at messing up my terminal, and when I clear it, I'm not looking to get anything back that was there before, so I just use `reset`. But ymmv.

Comment: How is that different to `Ctrl+L` for the purposes of this question?  The user didn't mention terminal corruption, and otherwise it's equivalent as far as I can see.

Comment: @Mikel I tried `Ctrl+L` but it did not clear the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

I usually just use:

```
clear
```

From the `clear` man page:

```
clear clears your screen if this is possible.  It looks in the environ-
ment for the terminal type and then in the terminfo database to  figure
out how to clear the screen.

clear ignores any command-line parameters that may be present.
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not clear the terminal.

Comment: @sawa: Can you provide a screenshot?  I still can't understand from your question why `clear` or `Ctrl+L` don't work.

Comment: @Mikel It just doesn't work. The line is scrolled up, and the cursor is at the first visible line, but the the scroll bar is positioned at the bottom.

Comment: @sawa: Ah, I see what you mean!  I was using PuTTY, and it was the same, but in Gnome Terminal there is a difference.  Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 5):

It's not an answer to your question, but you *can* use less, and maintain your color see:  https://serverfault.com/questions/26509/colors-in-bash-after-piping-through-less

hint:

```
$ grep --color=always foo bar.txt | less -r
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this command:

```
tput reset
```