# clear command in Konsole

Tags: linux, terminal, console, konsole

I know about the Linux `clear` command, but it just moves the previous output from the visible part of terminal window (KDE Konsole). I can still scroll up and see all previous text. Is there similar command that can erase entire content of a terminal window? (Something like clc in matlab.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands

Comment: true, sorry for that

Comment: @wesley not a dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/shell-console-clearing

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: Close but I don't actually think this is a duplicate. The answer is the same, but not the need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure you could make a command with `dbus`. But there is a shortcut for *clear scrollback and reset* by default. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: Does "Ctrl + shift + x" work only in `konsole`?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use anything else

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+X does not work for me in Konsole Version 2.12.3 Ctrl+Shift+K does work – see http://superuser.com/a/123196/664

Comment: Thanks @PiotrDobrogost, the Ctrl+Shift+K worked for me with a slightly older version of Konsole.

Answer (score 1):

`reset` is enough. No need to explicitly clear scrollback with it.

Comment: reset is not working in Konsole

Answer (score 1):

The `RIS` sequence (`\ec`) indeed doesn't clear history ([Bug 171598](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171598)), but in KDE 4 there's another sequence that does specifically clear history: `\e[3J` -- [Bug 158235](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158235).

Comment: It seems that Konsole version 21.12.3 requires both codes. `<ESC>c` clears the screen and `<ESC>[3J` deletes the scrollback buffer but doesn't clear the screen. As such, `echo -ne '\e[3J\ec'` should be able to clear the scrollback and the screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can set keyboard shortcut from...

**`setting` -> `configure keyboard shortcuts` -> search `clear scrollback and reset` -> set them!**